# Hash::make('password') returning different results at every call

Tags: php, hash, laravel-4, mcrypt, eloquent

So,the title basically describes my problem.
My Hash:make() is gone crazy.
I've created a users table with a hashed password, but I can't get Laravel to accept my credentials and I think the problem is in the Hash::make.

So, test this code:

```
Route::get('/',  function()
{
    return Hash::make('1234');
});
```

every time I hit route '/' it gives me a different hash.

Does it behave like that for everyone?
Any suggestions? I'm lost!

After Rocket tip, I've tried

```
    if(!Hash::check('1234', User::find(1)->password))
    return 'not';

$credentials = array(
        'email' => 'email@example.com',
        'password' => '1234',
        //'remember' => $remember   
    );
if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    return  View::make('hello');
}
return "Invalid Credentials";
```

But it keeps returning "Invalid Credentials".
I've double checked my auth.php and it's setup correctly.
Anything else I could try?

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing salt.

Comment: You don't need to run `Auth::check` yourself as the `Auth::attempt` does that for you. Have you changed the default `User` model in any way?

Comment: I didn't.The mysql table is users, the controller is User and the fields are email and password. It's factory settings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's what it's supposed to do.  It's supposed to create a different password each time, as it's creating a new random salt.

To check the user's password, you use the `check` method.

```
if(Hash::check('1234', $password)){
}
```

Or you can use `Auth::attempt`.

```
$user = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
);
if (Auth::attempt($user)){
}
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/security